# why do we need zone_highmem on x86?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

In linux kernel, `mem_map` is the array which holds all "struct page" descriptors. Those pages includes the 128MiB memory in lowmem for dynamically mapping highmem.

Since the lowmem size is 1GiB, so the `mem_map` array has only 1GiB/4KiB＝256KiB entries. If each entry size is 32 byte, then the `mem_map` memory size = 8MiB. But if we could use `mem_map` to map all 4GiB physical memory(if we have so much physical memory available on x86-32), then the mem_map array would occupy 32MiB, that is not a lot of kernel memory(or am i wrong?).

So my question is: why do we need to use that 128MiB in low for indirect highmem mapping in the first place? Or put another way, why not to map all those max 4GiB physical memory(if available) in the kernel space directly?

Note: if my understanding of the kernel source above is wrong, please correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look Here: http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch13.html

Kernel low memory is the 'real' memory map, addressed with 32-bit pointers on x86.

Kernel high memory is the 'virtual' memory map, addressed with virtual structures on x86.

You don't want to map it all into the kernel address space, because you can't always address all of it, and you need most of your memory for virtual memory segments (virtual, page-mapped process space.)

At least, that's how I read it.  Wow, that's a complicated question you asked.

To throw more confusion, chapter 13 talks about some PCI devices not being able to address the 32-bit space, which was the genesis of my previous comment:

On x86, some kernel memory usage is limited to the first Gigabyte of memory bacause of DMA addressing concerns.  I'm not 100% familiar with the topic, but there's a comapatibility mode for DMA on the PCI bus.  That may be what you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

3.6 GB is not the ceiling when using physical address extension, which is commonly needed on most modern x86 boards, especially with memory hotplug.

Answer (score 0):

> Or put another way, why not to map all those max 4GiB physical
>   memory(if available) in the kernel space directly?

One reason is userspace: every usespace process have its own virtual address space. Suppose you have 4Gb of RAM on x86. So if we suggest that kernel owns 1Gb of memory (~800 directly mapped + ~200 vmalloc) all other ~3Gb should be **dynamically** distributed between processes spinning in user space. So how can you map your 4Gbs directly when you have a several address spaces?

> why do we need zone_highmem on x86?

The reason is the same. Kernel reserves only ~800Mb for low mem. All other memory will be allocated and connected with particular virtual address only on demand. For example if you will execute a binary a new virtual address space will be created and some pages will be allocated for storing your binary code and data (heap ,stack ...). So the key attribute of high mem is to serve dynamic memory allocation requests, you never know in advance what will be triggered by userspace...